# Regex pattern matching for contains a character

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex pattern which can do this exactly.

1. Should match the length which is 12 characters alphaNumeric
2. Should also check for the occurrence of hyphen - twice in the word
3. No spaces are allowed.

I have tried the following regex:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*){2}$
```

*Some sample cases*

> -1234abcd-ab
>
> abcd12-avc-a
>
> -abcd-abcdacb
>
> ac12-acdsde-

**The regex should match for all the above.**

And should be wrong for the below

> -abcd-abcd--a
>
> abcd-abcdefg

I've been using this regex `^([a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*){2}$` for matching the above patterns, but the problem is, it doesn't have a length check of 12. I'm not sure how to add that into the above pattern. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: please post the pattern you have tried so far.

Comment: I've tried multitudes of regexes which are not working. I've gone through regexr and tried out all the combinations I know. But was of no use. @CodeManiac

Comment: can you post them, will help us to answer exactly what you were missing and also help you to learn too at the same time

Comment: ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*){2}$

This can be used to find a pattern with double hyphens, but I've no idea how to find the limit the overall length to 12 @CodeManiac

Comment: the easiest thing you can do in any language is check the length of string, `str.length <= 12`, if you want to do using regex you can use positive lookahead (which i will not suggest to use just for length restriction ), i.e `(?=^.{12}$)`

Comment: I am aware of that, but the solution has to be entirely regex. Because I already have regexes for various other patterns except this one. @CodeManiac

Comment: Yes you can use positive lookahead, see the updated comment, but IMO you should use `.length` for this restriction

Comment: edit your question and set your regex there.

Comment: @capt.swag please use the "Codeblock"

Comment: Instead of `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`, you can use `\p{Alnum}` or, if you don’t mind also accepting underscore, just `\w`. Besides that, why should `"-1234abcd-a"` match, despite it only has 11 characters and likewise, why is `"-abcd-abcd-ab"` a valid example when it contains three hyphens?

Comment: @Holger Sorry for that, two of the sample were wrong. I corrected it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

`(?=^.{12}$)(?=^[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+ /gm`

The first positive lookahead asserts the total length to be 12.
The second positive lookahead asserts the presence of exactly two hyphens.
Rest is just matching the possible characters in the character set.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GZFILn/3)

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Usage of \S* is what I was looking for.

Comment: @capt.swag: It's better to use `[^-]` instead of `\S` because the regex matches more than 2 hyphen, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/GZFILn/2)

Comment: Instead of `[^-]`, you can use `\w`, as the pattern shall accept only `[a-zA-Z0-9]` anyway. The only difference is that `\w` accepts `_`, which is sorted out in the subsequent `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+`. Alternatively, you could use `(?=^[^_]{12}$)\w*-\w*-\w*$`, sorting out `_` in the look-ahead already, so `\w` can only match the intended `[a-zA-Z0-9]` afterwards. The second `^` anchor also is unnecessary, as the look-ahead does already mandate it. But it might be clearer to place it right at the beginning, like `^(?=[^_]{12}$)\w*-\w*-\w*$`…